# SpringBoot 3, hibernate 6 tables not created

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm starting a brand new java project, based on

- java 17
- spring boot 3.1 → automatically import hibernate 6.2.2 final
- querydsl 5.0

I created a table using usual annotation

- @Table
- @Entity

the object implements Serializable

but when I start the application, database is not initialized.
I obviously put in the application.properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Application class is on the same package of the model and to be sure I added @EntityScan with root package name, but nothing happened.

I have not any error message, db connection is correctly established

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured the below properties properly? as its maybe create an issue while creating an table.

1. spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.provider_class
2. spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect
3. spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto

please check above and I think it will resolved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible causes:

1.Did you try running it with:

```
 spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

2.Your entity classes are in the same or in a sub-package relative one where you have you class with @EnableAutoConfiguration. If not
then your spring app does not see them and hence will not create
anything in db

3.Your application.properties must be in src/main/resources folder. Check your config, it seems that you are using some hibernate

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
As I wrote, I'm using hibernate 6.2.2, application.properties is correct because system correctly creates a connection to db and AutoConfiguration scope is correct too.
I added configuration you suggested but nothing changed :-/

Answer (score 0):

Everything was correct, I was checking wrong db via dbeaver

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).